# Can we display chr(10) (newline) in the Query Result Window? (SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer question (SQL Developer is the free IDE from Oracle - do not confuse with PL/SQL Developer, a different product):

The Query Result Window (where query results are shown) does not display newlines (`chr(10)`) embedded in text strings. That is, it will display the text `'one' || chr(10) || 'two'`, which should be displayed in a single table row but two lines of text, as `onetwo`. If one right-clicks the cell in the query result window and selects "Single Record View", the text is displayed correctly in two lines.

I checked Tools - Preferences - Database - Worksheet and I didn't see a setting for this behavior. Is there, in fact, a way to change it?

To illustrate the issue - consider this query run in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> select 'one' || chr(10) || 'two' as text_string from dual;

TEXT_ST
-------
one
two

1 row selected.
```

Notice the result is just one row (`1 row selected`) but the text is in two lines of text (still in a single row in the result set).

The same query in SQL Developer produces:

[image: SQL Developer screenshot]

Also: I am aware that I can get the "right" result (in two lines) if I run the statement as a script (F5 or Run Script button, instead of CTRL-ENTER or Run Statement button). I am not asking for a workaround; I am asking the question literally, is it possible to change the Query Result Window behavior.

Comment: You can, of course, "Run as Script" (F5 key).  That output will show the new lines.  That doesn't answer your question (how to get them shown in the query results window), but I mention it in the off-chance you didn't consider it.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - excellent; I was adding the last paragraph to my question right as you were posting your comment. You are right - I am aware of that, and that wasn't my question. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default grid view collapses that kind of whitespace. Doubleclick on the cell and you can activate a textarea for that specific cell.

Comment: Double-click is good to see an individual cell. I volunteered something very similar in my question, right-click and Single Record View, but what you propose is even better than that. Still, I am interested in the "grid view" itself; I would rather not have to double-click each individual cell to search for what I need. You mention the "default" grid - is there any other?

Comment: @mathguy The alterntive is what Matthew McPeak wrote, Run Script.

Comment: Again, I wasn't looking for an alternative (not sure how I could make that clearer). My alternative is that I copy the query from SQL Developer and run it in SQL\*Plus. I know how to work around the issue. I believe what you are saying is that "no, I didn't miss anything - we can't make SQL Developer query result window display newlines". That's what I wanted to know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: As far as I know, this kind of view was not designed for multiline display. You can of course file and issue as long as you have access to My Oracle Support with a contract.

Comment: No need (and no, I don't have access to Support - I am an amateur learning Oracle on my own, at home, I don't use it in any way other than running brief exercises... and I don't know if SQL Developer would fall under that anyway). I can run queries in SQL\*Plus whenever needed, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something. Cheers!